# Return Rows (Array) where the first 2 columns are bigger than 0.1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

An easy Example for what i want:

I have a Matrix with many columns where i want to keep rows, if the cells in the first 2 columns are (both!!) bigger than 0.1

something like that:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1,0,1],[1,2,5],[0,3,5],[0,0,2]])
B=np.zeros(4,3)
wildcard = np.vstack((B, A[A[:,0 and 1] > 0.1]))
```

obviously the "and" does not work, but that is what i want- both values in each line should be checked before they are returned to a new array where just the rows with these conditions remain.

Comment: Have you tried `wildcard = np.vstack((B, A[A[:2] > 0.1])`?

Comment: @aIKid You will have to do `np.all(A[:,:2] > 0.1, axis=-1)` for the boolean array.

Comment: Ah, i'm not familiar with numpy. Post that as an answer.

Comment: @Ophion this works but why [:,:2] ? since python starts indexing with 0 and what does axis=-1 here mean?

Comment: @user2956831, `[:, :2]` because python slices start at 0 but don't include the end point, so `[:2]` means `[0, 1]`.  `axis=-1` means "do the _all_ comparison along the _last_ axis."  In python, a negative index means "counting backwards from the end."  Here, the `-1` means compare along the last of these two axes: `[:, :2]`, which is the one that goes `:2`.  This of course is equivalent (since there are two axes, and `2-1 = 1`) to the `axis=1` in @Hammer's answer.

Answer (score 2):

instead of using and you can use &.  Extra parenthesis are required because & binds tighter than >

```
a[(a[:,0] > .1) & (a[:,1] > .1)]
```

The method proposed by Ophion in the comments works as well but is slower.

```
In [85]: b = np.random.random((100000,3))

In [86]: %timeit np.all(b[:,:2] > 0.1, axis = 1)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.99 ms per loop

In [87]: %timeit (b[:,0] > .1) & (b[:,1] > .1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 542 us per loop
```